# Does Android Studio automatically use correct layout

Tags: android, android-studio

I provided a few different layouts for my app, like landscape mode, tablets, large screens, etc.

Do I have to add anything in my code for when a user downloads my app I check how big their devices are and I set the correct layout myself? Or is that all done automatically and android detects the correct layout to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It generally detects the device's dimensions automatically and shows the appropriate layout for that. However, you need to make sure that you've put your layouts correctly. More on it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#alternative-layouts).

Answer (score 0):

Screen size resources in Android are handled by what's called [Alternative resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources) and qualifiers. No codes are required.

When you create a new layout, on Android studio, the dialog box show you the available qualifiers.

[image]

Behind the scene android studio create a subfolder hierarchy following the naming convention described in the link.

Example:
For screen orientation the available qualifiers are `port` and `land` and `square`. So you will end up with a folder structure like this

```
res
├── layout
│   └─── foo.xml
├── layout-land
│   └─── foo.xml
├── layout-port
│   └─── foo.xml
├── layout-square
│   └─── foo.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways in which you may describe the dimensions of a view.
If you keep the width (layout_width) to be 48dp, it'll be 48dp, irrespective of the screen size.
But, if you tell that the width should be the size of the view would be "match_parent" then based on the device size, the view width would be managed.

You may, however, choose to custom define the screens for landscape and portrait orientations, which means if the device is in a horizontal or in standing position.
You may also choose to give custom layout options for the various categories in which the screen size is categorized.
[image]

Read more: 
https://vinsol.com/blog/2014/11/20/tips-for-designers-from-a-developer/
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes